# Keeping remote files up to date but excluding some subdirectories

Tags: linux, sync, web, winscp

I have a web server running remotely on Linux and I'd like to sync my local fines to the server whenever there's a change. It needs to update when a local file is deleted or a new local file is added. A key function would be so it can have a config file we can share in the team, so another member could just run a script in the web root and keep the whole thing in sync. (config file would have to include specific folders/files it has to sync).

I have tried using Prepros with its file upload feature - it can't delete remote files and there's no filters.
I've been using WinSCP for now, but for example if I want to sync just two out of 5 directories, I have to run two instances of it.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With WinSCP, you can:

1. Use [file mask](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask) to exclude the directories/files you do not want to keep up to date.
2. Keep up to date only the selected directories/files.
   See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_keepuptodate#synchronize_options